# How to update GitHub forked repository using GitHub Desktop?

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I forked a repository using GitHub Desktop and made some changes.
Now I want check in those changes to base repository?
I want get changes from base repository with clear difference between base file and modified files, like what we see in winmerge?

Comment: Why are you adding asp and ide tags to the question, is the question beyond using git?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-desktop%5D+update+forked+repository

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/). It has excellent built-in diffs views, and you can select any two points in your local repo to view the changes that have occurred in between. Available for macOS, Windows, and Linux. The free version works well for what you're looking to do.

You can create a new branch on your local and pull from the base repo if you want to see how the HEAD there has changed (again, you can use GitKraken to view the changes that have taken place since you forked the repo). You can then easily merge or rebase the new branch to your master if you want to include the upstream changes to your local repository. Again, GitKraken makes merges and rebases super easy as compared to trying to resolve them on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

The Git Desktop has a "Changes" tab. This should list all the files which were modified. When selecting each file it shows the changes made to it compared to Base repo.

I would recommend using command line. Generally not all of the features are implemented in the UI based tools and they don't come with all the options provided by command line.

If you haven't already installed, install git for the platform. For windows, you can get it from "https://git-scm.com/download/win".

Open `git bash` and cd to the repo and execute `gitk`. The files and their changes should be shown under the "Local uncommitted changes, not checked in to index"

Couple of other useful commands:

```
git status -suno   --> List all tracked files which were modified.
git diff           --> Shows all the changes made.
```

Hope it helps!